# JQuery UI dialog external css

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

```
$('#add_remarks').click(function(){
    $( "#remark-form" ).dialog( "open" );
});
$( "#remark-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        'Add Remarks': function() {
                alert('ok')
                },
                error: function(){
                    //alert('error');
                    //location.reload();
                }
            });
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $(this).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
});
```

I would like to specify an external css class so I can define the width and the height 
of the remark-form from an external css file.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: If the external CSS file is loaded into the site, you can still reference the selectors contained within the file as you normally would...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem/question is here.

Comment: I answered your question and then realized there's really no need for doing this...so really I don't get your question either. Haha!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addClass` to..well, add a class to the div on which you're calling the .dialog. And then you can style that anyway you wish. So your code would become

```
$( "#remark-form" ).addClass('your_class').dialog({
autoOpen: false,
modal: true,
buttons: {
    'Add Remarks': function() {
            alert('ok')
            },
            error: function(){
                //alert('error');
                //location.reload();
            }
        });
    },
    Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog( "close" );
    }
},
close: function() {
    allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
}});
```

Comment: Plus you need to pass `width: 'auto', height: 'auto'` to the dialog constructor.

Answer (score 1):

you can use dialogClass:

```
 $( "#selector" ).dialog({ dialogClass: 'myClass' });
```

Answer (score 0):

from [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) you provided at theming tab, rendered html codes will look like:

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable">
   <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
      <span id="ui-dialog-title-dialog" class="ui-dialog-title">Dialog title</span>
      <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" href="#"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a>
   </div>
   <div style="height: 200px; min-height: 109px; width: auto;" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" id="dialog">
      <p>Dialog content goes here.</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

so as you have `#remark-form` selector for your item, all you need:

```
#remark-form .ui-dialog { height: 100px !impportant; width 100px !important}
```

then you could this style code to head section of your html document or external css then you point it

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add an CSS after the loading of the page (if you have a dynamic CSS file, for example), you can use

```
function includeCSSFile( file_url ) {
    var cssFile = document.createElement('link');
    cssFile.setAttribute('type', "text/css" );
    cssFile.setAttribute('rel', "stylesheet" );
    cssFile.setAttribute('href', file_url );
    document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).appendChild(cssFile);
}
```

on your main javascript file, so anywhere you want to load another css you have to call the function like

```
includeCssFile ( 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bad+Script' )
```

and after that you can use an $(selector).addClass(...) on your code.

i'm using it on a site and its working fine, where the link_url is given by a PHP script, and sometimes it is written dynamically...